# Monitor.Enter: No overload for method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I recently inherited some code that I can't get to build yet.  Here's the offending line:

```
Monitor.Enter(this.foo, ref lockTaken);
```

According to Visual Studios there is only one definition and it takes a single argument but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.100).aspx) the two argument version should exist.  Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What framework are you targeting? That overload was added in .NET 4.

Comment: I was targeting .NET 2.  That solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Okay, will write that up as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced in .NET 4. So as you were targeting .NET 2.0, it wasn't present.

When in doubt, check the "Version information" section at the bottom of the documentation.

Admittedly I'd normally be at least *slightly* nervous about manual calls to `Monitor.Enter`/`Exit` anyway - in 99% of cases, using `lock` is a better idea.

Comment: Oh no doubt on using lock.  This code is a nightmare.  Thanks for the help.